# How to disable context menu on long pen press?

Tags: windows-7, digitization, graphics-tablet, pen

I have wacom bamboo pen. When I am pressing it for a log time, circle animation appears and then context menu called. This makes impossible to draw something slowly. How to disable context menu call on long press? The pen has special button for context menu, so long press processing is absolutely not needed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Caveat: I don't have a Bamboo, I've got a Tablet PC but what you're describing sounds like the right click press-and-hold action which you can disable/tweak as follows:

(if you're in category mode) 
Go to the Control Panel, 'Hardware and Sound' and then 'Change tablet pen settings'

[image: Control panel category mode path to pen/tablet options]

(if you're in icon mode)
or 'Pen and Touch'

[image: Control panel icon mode path to pen/tablet options]

Once inside, you'll see this dialog, and you want to change the settings on the press and hold action.

[image]

If you need to use the registry to alter this setting (Editing the Default Profile for example), it can be found in a DWORD key named TouchMode_hold, located in

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Tablet

Setting this value to 0 disables the behaviour.

Comment: Also don't forget to restart graphic editor after changing this setting. I had issue with gimp which after changing of settings was still causing a problem *without* showing up right click menu but still showing circle as it usually do on right click.