# Press and hold - cant turn off windows 10 wacom

Tags: windows-10

After recent update, don't know if from the Wacom Drivers or Windows. I cant turn off the press and hold function on the tablet and it's driving me crazy while it hindering normal workflow.

I've set the disable press and hold function in the windows settings, changed tome values i regedit according [How to disable context menu on long pen press?](https://superuser.com/questions/418830/how-to-disable-context-menu-on-long-pen-press)

You can see it here, I cant click and drag the color pins, and when pressing the menu still appears.
https://youtu.be/KSOSqaTmmcw

Answer (score 0):

The updated Wacom drivers fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn off Window's Ink if you want Photoshop to work right--at least, as of this current moment of WX (1909, build 18363-720) and Wacom driver version (6.3.38-2).

The only way to fix this properly is to edit the registry (make sure to export a backup before you do this):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\SysEventParameters

change HoldMode to "3." Then the demon circle will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, and windows 10 isn't responding to any commands entered through their new little Pen and Ink section. Unchecking those options does nothing for me. Wacom added a button inside the driver for the pen under Grip Pen > Mapping. Look for "Use windows ink". Uncheck that and you're good!